# Docusign envelope says it was sent, but I never get the email

Tags: docusignapi

I sent a one document envelope to two people, myself and someone else. I never get the email, even though the envelope summary says it was sent out. When I go into Docusign, I see the envelope and it has the status "Need to Sign" with a blue exclamation point. It has the correct info on the two signers. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Here is what I sent and the reply:

```
{
  "name": "Kathy Lori",
  "email": "kathylori@xxx.com",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "accessCode": "12345",
  "customFields": [],
  "routingOrder": "1",
  "note": "",
  "roleName": "##Buyer1"
}
{
  "name": "Kathy Keaton",
  "email": "KathyKeatonxxx@xxx.com",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "accessCode": "12345",
  "customFields": [],
  "routingOrder": "2",
  "note": "",
  "roleName": "##Seller1"
}
{
  "documentId": "1",
  "name": "\\\\01filpr001\\hardink$\\Here is document three of the test.docx",
  "fileExtension": ".docx",
  "documentFields": [],
  "documentBase64": [bytearray]
}
{
  "documentId": "1",
  "name": "c:\document three of the test.docx"
}
email subject: Here is the subject
return url: http://requestb.in/10vkzq71


status back is:
{
  "envelopeId": "57d44b8d-33e4-45a0-adbf-b95b7b1ddea5",
  "uri": "/envelopes/57d44b8d-33e4-45a0-adbf-b95b7b1ddea5",
  "statusDateTime": "2017-03-13T20:37:08.0206424Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to the vendor. (Also, check your spam folder.)

Comment: Have you specified any routing order for the recipients. A recipient will only get an email if the earlier recipients in the routing order have completed signing. As @ceejayoz suggested, please check your spam folder. Also, can you please post you Json, so that an accurate answer can be provided.

Comment: Here is what I am sending and the response:

Comment: I also noticed that very recently, a number of these emails are going into spam. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: emails being sent to Spam has very little to do with Docusign. It could be related to the recipient's email hosting provider and the spam filters that the recipient might have applied to their mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The envelope request has two recipients at different routing orders.

- Routing Order 1 ( "roleName": "##Buyer1")
- Routing Order 2 ("roleName": "##Seller1")

When the envelope is sent, the recipient role "##**Buyer1**" will receive the email.

Recipient specified at the role "##**Seller1**" will only receive the email after "##**Buyer1**" finishes signing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the first person is not getting the email. But if I go up to Docusign, it lists both these recipients with a need to sign status.

Comment: "_it lists both these recipients with a need to sign status_" . This is the expected behavior as both the recipients are yet to sign. What happens if you send an envelope with a single recipient? Is the recipient still not getting the email? Also, Have you tried resending the envelope?

Comment: I can confirm from the Docusign email logs that we had successfully sent out an email at _2017-03-13T20:37:09.9070501Z_ to the email address you have specified at _routing Order 1_,  for the envelope Id _57d44b8d-33e4-45a0-adbf-b95b7b1ddea5_